# Getting the current active language in chrome via javaScript (Chrome 66 Stable)

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I am working with chrome and trying to detect the current language being used.

window.navigator.language returns a language

window.navigator.languages returns all languages added in chrome

Plastered all over the internet I am told window.navigator.language does the job of finding the **Active** language.
However this is no longer the case. It just returns whatever is first in the list, i.e en-US however as you can see it's not guaranteed to be the active language, I suspect because of the new design. I am wondering if someone has found a solution for a more modern chrome.

That is to say I am given no information to destinguish between which is the active language based on my preferences.

[image]

NOTE: I have also sent a request to my server and inspected the header, the same information is given as above.
[image]

```
accept-language: en-AU,en-GB;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.7,es-ES;q=0.6,es;q=0.5
```

Is just a reflection of the order in which the preferred languages are displayed, this doesn't tell me which ones is the active language and which isn't.

Doesn't matter if the active browser language is en-GB or es-ES the same header information is given with the same weights.

Comment: So you mean the language that is being used for the browser's menu right? Why do you care about that?

Comment: Note that this *displayed language* options seems to be only available for Windows users, on linux and mac it uses the system language and there is no option to change it... (based on https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/173424?hl=en&vid=0-56587123991-1526629005067&visit_id=1-636622258613266368-2151817906&rd=1)

Comment: To trigger a language translation library. With all due respect it doesn't matter why I need something does it?

Comment: Yes it matters because based on the needs we can find alternatives. Also it allows to determine if we are facing an [XY-problem](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/XyProblem). And I still don't see why your language translation library doesn't simply respect users settings.

Answer (score 0):

**If you want the language on the first position than you can use this code:**

```
 var browserLanguage = navigator.language || navigator.userLanguage;
```

Works for me with the newest version of chrome:
[image]

**If you want the displayed language, that's another story:**

What javascript can see is the HttpRequest header.
For example:

[image: Accept-language httprequest header]

You can see a field Accept-Language that tells the server which languages you want to see.
[RFC 7231 5.3.1.](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-5.3.1)

> *Note that some recipients treat the order in which language tags are
> listed as an indication of descending priority, particularly for tags
> that are assigned equal quality values (no value is the same as q=1).
> However, this behavior cannot be relied upon.  For consistency and to
> maximize interoperability, many user agents assign each language tag
> a unique quality value while also listing them in order of decreasing
> quality.  Additional discussion of language priority lists can be
> found in Section 2.3 of [RFC4647].*

What that means is that the browser will add weight to each tag and then sort them decreasing (no q is q=1 so the maximum).

So it's normal that you can't see the displayed language because these are your personal browser settings. Apps on a mobile device can access browser settings but regular websites can't.

Comment: Hi JoaVer go to language settings select a language that isn't the first one in the list as the "google chrome is displayed in this language" and run it again. It just returns whatever is at the 0th index.

Comment: Thanks for updating your answer. I have seen this example of the header around. And I have inspected the header information before but I wants provided this weighting. How exactly did you get that information? From what context is that snap-shop?

Comment: this is just an example i found online but in chrome it's open inspector(ctrl+shift+i) ==> network ==> then of course reload the page so it can captate your request ==> then click on the row that is of type document and the headers will appear on the right.